# Is Allah with us? Does he still tell us signs etc...?

Tags: allah, revelation

Salam

A question was posted here today regarding Allah and his signs.
A fellow poster responded saying that Allah guides us through the Quran, which is true.

However something struck within me, prompting me to wonder and ask.....

We know Allah is always here and undeniably exists.
But is he always with us? Does he still guide us, show us signs etc... ? We know whatever happens is already written by Allah and Allah knows all but when we remember him, do salah and dua....does he listen?

I ask because we know the revelation came and our prophet Muhammed .s.a.w (pbuh) delivered the message (la illaha illilah Muhammad doorah solillah). After which no more revelation....so it questions on why there is no more revelation or signs?

Comment: I've always considered that the world itself is a sign; a kitab that is itself veiled.

Answer (score 1):

Wa Alaikumu Salam wa Ramatulahi wa Barakatuh.

From Quran[50:16]:

> And We have already created man and know what his soul whispers to
>   him, and We are closer to him than [his] jugular vein

About guidance, knowing what is right from wrong, is a great indicator of your closeness to Allah (swt) and Allah(swt) guide those who are closest to him. Indeed he is the owner of Wisdom and Knowledge, he bestows upon whom so ever he will.

Other ways that Allah (swt) may guide you is that you remember often Allah(swt), his prophets and messengers. Their stories indeed in it there is guidance and many reminders for those who have faith.

In other cases Allah(swt) may bestow upon you "Good" dreams and "True" dreams.

> It was narrated from ‘Awf ibn Maalik that the Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Dreams are of three
>   types: some are terrifying things from the Shaytaan, aimed at causing
>   grief to the son of Adam; some are things that a person is concerned
>   with when he is awake, so he sees them in his dreams; and some are a
>   part of the forty-six parts of Prophecy.”
>
> (Saheeh Sunan Ibn Maajah, 3155)

But the signs of Allah(swt) are everywhere, in your surrounding, high above and even within yourself.

---

So why is there no more revelation, because Allah(swt) has decreed and promised that his Quran will remain until an appointed time.

> From ‘Abd-Allaah ibn Mas’ood, who said: “Something will come and take
>   the Qur’aan one night and not one aayah will be left, either in the
>   Mus-haf or in the heart of any person, but it will be taken away.”
>   (Narrated by al-Daarimi with a saheeh isnaad, no. 3209)

May Allah(swt) forgive me if i made any mistake for blame there is only myself and shaytan. May Allah (swt) guide us always on the straight path and always make us truthful sincere muslims.

Ameen!

Answer (score 0):

My experience is when I pray and recite Quran at night  : I see visions and doors opens every where with almost everybody .

and when I stop that a lot of good things stop happen , it is like why do you stop after I gave you that ?!

I understand it from hadith that Mohamed said "Don't be like Folan(Someone) was praying at night then left it" Bukhari : 1152 .